# React Chartjs will not accept a new value and update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I am trying to draw a chart with Chartjs and React. It should be empty until the value (array) updates. I am able to successfully change the value but the chart will not draw the new bar. calcInfo() updates the colors and labels correctly. I am pretty new to React and have tried a ton of different things but have not gotten anywhere. There are some extra calls and variables in there as I have been trying everything I can think of.

```
var scores = [50];
var count = [];
var colors = [];
var border= [];

class BarGraph extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data:[]
    }            
    scores = [this.state.data];
    this.drawChart = this.drawChart.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

drawChart() {
    var barChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
            type: 'bar',
            labels: count,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Data',
                    data: [this.state.data],
                    backgroundColor: colors,
                    borderColor: border,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                }
            ],
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                mode: null,
                legend: { display: false },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true,
                            color: "rgba(201,201,201)"
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            max: 100
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
         })
        }

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawChart();
}

componentDidMount() {

}

handleChange(e) {
    var scoreValue;
    scoreValue = document.getElementById("data").value;
    e.preventDefault();
    scoreValue = 50;
    scores = [scoreValue];
    this.calcInfo();
    this.state = {data: [scoreValue]};
    this.setState(this.state);
    this.componentDidUpdate();
    console.log(this.state.data);
    console.log(scores);
    alert("hello")
}

calcInfo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            var ref1 = 0;
            var ref2 = 0;
            if (scores[i] <= 10) {
                ref1 = 255;
                ref2 = 30;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 20) {
                ref1 = 220;
                ref2 = 53;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 30) {
                ref1 = 180;
                ref2 = 75;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 40) {
                ref1 = 150;
                ref2 = 87;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 50) {
                ref1 = 115;
                ref2 = 100;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 60) {
                ref1 = 90;
                ref2 = 120;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 70) {
                ref1 = 50;
                ref2 = 145;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 80) {
                ref1 = 25
                ref2 = 180;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 90) {
                ref1 = 0;
                ref2 = 220;
            } else if (scores[i] <= 100) {
                ref1 = 0;
                ref2 = 255;
            }
            colors[i] = 'rgba(' + ref2 + ',' + ref1 + ',0, 0.7)';
            border[i] = 'rgba(' + ref2 + ',' + ref1 + ',0, 1)';
            count[i] = i + 1;
        }
}

render() {
   this.calcInfo();
    return (
        <div style={{flex:1}}>
            <input id="data" onChange={this.drawChart.bind(this)}/> 
        <canvas style={{height:'500px'}} id="bar-chart" width="100%" redraw></canvas>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    'mapData' : state.mapData,
    'chartData' :state.chartData
}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {

    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)

ReactDOM.render(<BarGraph />, 
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There is quite a lot of code in your post. If you can remove non-essential details, other users will be better able to understand the issue and provide good answers.

Comment: Couple of issues in your code:
1) export it as `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BarGraph)`;
2) the props you will be getting in `BarGraph` are `mapData` and `chartData`. Use `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle method and compare these props and render instead of componentDidUpdate

Comment: It looks like you have Redux in your project. You’d need to share at least your reducer. Also please clarify if you intend to load data from the Redux store or whether it’s coming from elsewhere. I’d recommend to take a look at the connect() method and make sure you are passing BarGraph to it.

Comment: There were definitely multiple issues with this code. I ended up having to ditch react for this project since it will not work with other stuff, in this case jsp. Thank you all for your help.